# De HTML a PDF en MVC 5 ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, pdf

Muchachos tengo una vista como esta
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

eso se supone es una factura para clientes, ya imprime pero necesito que el usuario pueda descargar un pdf y eso ha sido imposible
probe del lado del cliente con varias librerias js como jsPDF, pero esta opcion lo que hace es descargarme un pdf con una imagen muy fea del documento o la facutra

realmente estoy muy perdido como hago para que el usuario pueda descargar esa pantalla en un pdf pero que arroje exactamente lo mismo que esta viendo?

Comment: Echale un ojo a **SelectPdf** es una libreria que convierte vistas a PDF, la puedes integrar a tu proyecto mediante **NuGet** NuGet : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Select.Pdf/ Sitio : https://selectpdf.com/community-edition/

Comment: voy a probar amigo

Comment: Y como estás realizando el proceso de impresión? desde el servidor o desde el cliente?

Comment: desde el cliente con javascript

Comment: Hola, has probado a imprimir via el navegador? Con la opción de imprimir puedes elegir la impersora y dentro de ellas Microsoft Print PDF. prueba a ver qué tal sale

Comment: ps si amigo eso es una gran solución, el problema es q la cliente es un poco molestoncilla y quiere un bendito boton para descargar el pdf a través de un botón, la verdad me ha pagado muy bien asi q ni modo, hay alguna forma de atraves de javascript llamar a Microsoft Print PDF ?

Comment: Podes usar varias librerías que convierten tu vista en Pdf. Son muy simples de utilizar. * La más fácil y rápida de usar es [Rotativa](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa).
* La otra es [NReco](https://www.nrecosite.com/pdf_generator_net.aspx). Tiene una versión free y una paga. Hay más pero estas son con las que yo trabajo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

muchas gracias por ayudarme, les comento que por fin pude hacer lo que queria pongo el código por si alguien algún dia necesita esto:

```
    public ActionResult CreatorPDF(string consecutive)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> cookieCollection = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var key in Request.Cookies.AllKeys)
        {
            cookieCollection.Add(key, Request.Cookies.Get(key).Value);
        }
        string nameFile = consecutive.ToLower().Contains("cot") ? string.Format("{0}.pdf", consecutive) :
            string.Format("{0}-{1}.pdf",ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PrefixEstablishment"],consecutive);
        var pdf = new ActionAsPdf(string.Format("OrderInvoice/{0}", consecutive)) {
            Cookies = cookieCollection,
            PageSize =Rotativa.Options.Size.A4,
            CustomSwitches = "--print-media-type",
            PageMargins = {Left=1,Right=1},
            FileName = nameFile,
        };
        return pdf;
    }
```

observaciones:
*el foreach, mantiene la sesion activa al momento de generar el pdf, esto evita que genere un pdf de la pagina de login
*la variable string nameFile se puede obviar es algo que he puesto para verificar si el usuario genera una cotizacion o una factura real

listo eso es todo muchachos.

Answer (score 0):

lo he conseguido, parcialmente: agrege el nuguet Rotativa.Mvc, y el codigo es este:

```
    public ActionResult GeneratePDF()
    {
        return new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("aqui la vista" );
    }
```

el problema es que me bota un pdf pero con la pagina de login de la aplicacion jaja parece que por algo pierde el login ustedes que piensan?

Comment: Creo que implicaría mas desarrollo: ¿qué posibilidad hay de enviarle credenciales generales para permitir acceder a esta vista?. Otra opción es desde el lado cliente invoque `window.print()` vea este [enlace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp).

Comment: Hola, por qué en tu acción GeneratePDF() no cargas el modelo que usa la vista de impresión y luego usas `return new ViewAsPdf("DemoViewAsPDF", model);`